# In the playground, how to turn off debug mode?

Tags: xcode6, debug-mode

I wanted to disable debug mode in Xcode 6 playground, but can't find how to do it. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I wasn't able to find any official sources for what I'm writing now; but how should playground be able to work without debugging?

Playground doesn't simply execute your application and then shows your results nor does it execute your application step by step.

Xcode uses JIT compiling (just-in-time; Swift needs to be compiled) for your code (and every change you do) and then executes your binary and shows some information about your code which it considers useful.

So what it does is debugging your code but without the necessity for you to set breakpoints and check the state of your vars or return values on your own.

So you could consider it as some kind of real-time-debugging.

At least this is how I understood how things are going.